# Set AVAudioPlayer as input data source for AVAudioSession

Tags: ios, audio, avaudioplayer, voip, avaudiosession

I am wondering if it is possible to specify an AVAudioPlayer as an input device for AVAudioSession. I want to play a sound through a VoIP application through the microphone for the other party to hear and I don't know how to go about this, if it is even possible.

Any help is appreciated, the docs are vague and I know this is not kosher programming, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, if you go in AVAudioSession.h header file (or apple documentation) you will see a list of available in/out ports. Besides that, Apple doesn't want you to have the ablity to steal music from other apps >)

```
    #pragma mark -- constants for port types --

/* input port types */
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVAudioSessionPortLineIn       NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0); /* Line level input on a dock connector */
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInMic   NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0); /* Built-in microphone on an iOS device */
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVAudioSessionPortHeadsetMic   NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0); /* Microphone on a wired headset.  Headset refers to an
                                                                                   accessory that has headphone outputs paired with a
                                                                                   microphone. */
/* output port types */
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVAudioSessionPortLineOut          NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0); /* Line level output on a dock connector */
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVAudioSessionPortHeadphones       NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0); /* Headphone or headset output */
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVAudioSessionPortBluetoothA2DP    NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0); /* Output on a Bluetooth A2DP device */
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInReceiver  NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0); /* The speaker you hold to your ear when on a phone call */
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInSpeaker   NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0); /* Built-in speaker on an iOS device */
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVAudioSessionPortHDMI             NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0); /* Output via High-Definition Multimedia Interface */
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVAudioSessionPortAirPlay          NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0); /* Output on a remote Air Play device */
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVAudioSessionPortBluetoothLE      NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0); /* Output on a Bluetooth Low Energy device */

/* port types that refer to either input or output */
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVAudioSessionPortBluetoothHFP NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0); /* Input or output on a Bluetooth Hands-Free Profile device */
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVAudioSessionPortUSBAudio     NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0); /* Input or output on a Universal Serial Bus device */
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVAudioSessionPortCarAudio     NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0); /* Input or output via Car Audio */
```